# DNN - Redirecting to installation wizard

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am configuring my Production Version DNN on other machine, but it is always redirecting to the installation wizard page.

I have googled over it and tried below mentioned solutions.

1. re-checked database connection
2. re-checked database is not corrupt.
3. tried to change below settings to `false`. by doing so, its redirecting to `Install/UnderConstruction.htm` page.

Can anybody help me to find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to /install/install.aspx what displays on that page?

I would be willing to bet money that it says the database connection fails, there is something you are missing in your DB setup, or connection string, that isn't working properly.

Comment: @chirs, not sure but seems source code was not full. replaced source code from latest download and it worked. :D